# pandas: split index string and sum up rows of equal slices

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split the row index strings of a DataFrame and sum rows of equals slices. Something like:

```
idx       val1 val2 val3
con-991-1 1    1    1
con-991-2 1    0    1
con-732   0    0    0
con-55-1  1    0    1
con-55-2  0    1    1
```

turn to:

```
con-991   2    1    2
con-732   0    0    0
con-55    1    1    2
```

Here goes what I have so far:

```
df = DataFrame()
df['new'] = df1.index
df = DataFrame(df.new.str.split('-').tolist(), index=df1.index, columns=['pre', 'med', 'sux'])
dfnew = concat([df1, df], axis=1, ignore_index=False)
dfnew['index'] = dfnew.index
dfnew.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
#dfnew.index = MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(dfnew['index'], dfnew[1])), names=['base1', 'base2'])           
print(dfnew.groupby(['index', 'med']).sum())
```

My code is not working and also is definitely not pythonic.
Is there a better way to do that?
Best.

Answer (score 17):

I don't think you were that far off in approach.  First, construct a new series that you want to group by, and then call `sum`:

```
>>> new_index = df.index.to_series().str.split("-").str[:2].str.join("-")
>>> df.groupby(new_index).sum()
         val1  val2  val3
idx                      
con-55      1     1     2
con-732     0     0     0
con-991     2     1     2
```

or maybe

```
>>> df.groupby(new_index, as_index=False).sum()
       idx  val1  val2  val3
0   con-55     1     1     2
1  con-732     0     0     0
2  con-991     2     1     2
```

---

It might help to break `new_index` down.  Instead of adding a new series to the frame so that we can access the `str` methods, we can simply call `to_series`:

```
>>> df.index
Index([u'con-991-1', u'con-991-2', u'con-732', u'con-55-1', u'con-55-2'], dtype='object')
>>> df.index.to_series()
idx
con-991-1    con-991-1
con-991-2    con-991-2
con-732        con-732
con-55-1      con-55-1
con-55-2      con-55-2
Name: idx, dtype: object
```

And then split, like you did:

```
>>> df.index.to_series().str.split("-")
idx
con-991-1    [con, 991, 1]
con-991-2    [con, 991, 2]
con-732         [con, 732]
con-55-1      [con, 55, 1]
con-55-2      [con, 55, 2]
Name: idx, dtype: object
```

And then we can use slicing to take the first two elements of each list:

```
>>> df.index.to_series().str.split("-").str[:2]
idx
con-991-1    [con, 991]
con-991-2    [con, 991]
con-732      [con, 732]
con-55-1      [con, 55]
con-55-2      [con, 55]
Name: idx, dtype: object
```

And finally we `join`:

```
>>> df.index.to_series().str.split("-").str[:2].str.join("-")
idx
con-991-1    con-991
con-991-2    con-991
con-732      con-732
con-55-1      con-55
con-55-2      con-55
Name: idx, dtype: object
```

Comment: The `.str[:2]` just changed my life :D